# Unable to use set_index() using pandas package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas 
df6 = pandas.read_csv("https://www.pythonhow.com/supermarkets.csv")
df6.set_index('test')
```

I expect the output to add a row title "test" but returns with 
the following error in my jupyter notebook.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\sunair raj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'fdfdf'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 0):

`.set_index()` is trying to take a column and make it the index. Since you don't have any columns named `test`, it is failing.

Not sure how you are getting the error message you posted, as `fdfdf` is no where to be found.

What are you trying to do exactly? What should the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

From your post, seems like you want to set your index a name called 'test'. This is not `set_index` method do. set_index will take a column which should have existed in your dataset and make it as index. So from your goal, this line should be what you are looking for:

```
df6.index.name = 'test'
```